# Не работает ссылка на Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть 2 контроллера `Home` и `Agree` в каждом из них по одному методу `Index`. В представлении из контроллера `Home` есть такой вот код

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "Index", "Agree")
```

Который должен ссылаться на метод Index из контроллера Agree. Однако при загрузке этого представления появляется вот такая ссылка

```
<a href="/Agree">Click</a>
```

Почему так выходит ? Оба метода без параметров. Роут по умолчанию

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ссылка ведет на контроллер `Agree` с action - `Index`.

`ActionLink` "сокращает" ссылку, выбрасывая из нее параметры со значением, равным дефолтному. У вас дефолтное значения для `action` - `Index`, а для `controller` - `Home`. Т.е.

`/Agree/Index` будет сокращено до `/Agree`

`/Home/Index` будет сокращено до `/`

Comment: Спасибо ! Точно